# Error loading graphql with react-relay modern

Tags: reactjs, react-native, babeljs, graphql, relayjs

I am developing an react-native application using Relay for working with graphql. 
Before earlier versions I have been using Relay classic with RootContainer and renderer following the 'sibelius' [react-native-relay-example](https://github.com/sibelius/react-native-relay-example) also combined with these two posts: [first](http://www.mot.la/2016-05-08-getting-started-with-react-native-and-relay.html) and 
[second](https://medium.com/@salujaharkirat/using-react-native-with-relay-18b940c2403c).

So I have changed the react-relay version from 0.10.0 to 1.0.0 and for starters put a simple query at first screen using relay modern implementation. I did not change babel-relay-plugin. When ever I run the app I get`graphql: Unexpected invocation at runtime. Either the Babel transform was not set up, or it failed to identify this call site. Make sure it is being used verbatim as 'graphql'`

I am also a starter at developing react-native apps and overall using graphql so I have this constant feeling I am missing something not mentioned in the docs which I suppose to already know when working with react.

This is my .babelrc file:

```
{
  "plugins": ["./data/babelRelayPlugin"],
  "presets": ["react-native"]
}
```

babelRelayPlugin.js

```
const getBabelRelayPlugin = require('babel-relay-plugin');
const schemaData = require('./schema.json');
module.exports = getBabelRelayPlugin(schemaData.data);
```

I am creating a RelayEnvironment which I am importing to the QueryRenderer:

```
import {
  Environment,
  Network,
  Store,
  RecordSource
} from 'relay-runtime';

const fetchQuery = (operation, variables, cacheConfig, uploadables) => {
  return (
    fetch('https://../graphql', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          query: operation.text,
          variables,
        }),
      }).then( response => {
        return response.json();
      }).catch( err => console.log(err) )
  );
}

const source = new RecordSource();
const store = new Store(source);
const network = Network.create(fetchQuery);
const handlerProvider = null;

export const RelayEnvironment = new Environment({
  handlerProvider,
  network,
  store,
});
```

This is my QueryRenderer in jsx:

```
        <QueryRenderer
          environment={ RelayEnvironment }
          query={ graphql`query {
            content(path: "/latest-updates"){
              title
              children{
                entries{
                  key: id
                  title
                  flyTitle
                  teaser
                  mainImageObj{
                    path
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }` }
          render={ ({error, props}) => {
            if(error){
              console.log(error);
            } else if(props) {
              console.log(props);
              return <Text> Done </Text> ;
            } else {
              console.log('loading...');
            }
          }}
        />
```

If I run this query in graphiql I do get the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`babel-relay-plugin` is now `babel-plugin-relay` in Relay Modern, and the usage isn't the same anymore - [see here](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/relay-modern.html#set-up-babel-plugin-relay).

You need 3 things now:

- Your schema in GraphQL notation, in a separate file (it is the string you pass to [buildSchema](http://graphql.org/graphql-js/utilities/#buildschema))
- `yarn add -D babel-plugin-relay` - you do not need to make a custom one anymore
- To install and run the `relay-compiler` in the background

Here is how it works:

- You pass your schema to the relay-compiler via command-line and run it on your sources: `relay-compiler --src ./src --schema path/schema.graphql`
- The relay compiler generates definitions for your queries in a folder called `__generated__` next to your files
- The `babel-plugin-relay` replaces your queries by a `require()` call to the corresponding generated GraphQL definition by the relay compiler

---

## Example setup and usage

`yarn add -D babel-plugin-relay relay-compiler`

Directory structure

```
schema.graphql
src/
  App.js
.babelrc
package.json
```

schema.graphql

```
type Query {
  user: User!
}

type User {
  name: String!
}
```

src/App.js

```
// ...

const myQuery = graphql`
  query App_ExampleQuery {
    user {
      name
    }
  }
`;

// ...
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "plugins": ["relay"]
}
```

package.json

```
...
"scripts": {
  "relay": "relay-compiler --src ./src --schema ./schema.graphql --watch",
},
...
```

**Then, run `yarn relay` or `npm run relay` in a separate terminal.**
Start your app as usual.

Comment: Does it has to be a .graphql file or can I use the schema.js ?

Comment: @parohy It can also be a JSON file, but it can't be your exported `.js` file.

Comment: Have a look at `printSchema` (http://graphql.org/graphql-js/utilities/#printschema) to convert your JS schema to a `.graphql` schema

Comment: Overall you should be using directly GraphQL notation, it will be easier developping with -as the ecosystem is built around it

Comment: You'll also enjoy building schema with the GraphQL notation more :)

Comment: I understand. So I did the changes as described. I have added `relay-compiler`, set the script and managed to run it. Now it waits at `Watching for changes to default...` . Should I also `yarn add relay` to the project? When I add relay to plugins it throws a TransformError uknown plugin "relay". If I remove it and rebuild/rerun, it starts loading and it throw the same error as mentioned in my post.

Comment: I edited my answer, I didn't notice of the plugin changed too ; it is now `babel-plugin-relay` and not `babel-relay-plugin`. Install `babel-plugin-relay` and the TransformError should disappear.

Comment: From what you're saying, the `relay-compiler` looks OK now

Comment: Thank you so much! Its ALIVE!