# Where does `yarn run react` fit into the Relay workflow?

Tags: react-native, graphql, relay

I'm trying to get Relay working with my React Native app and talking to my GraphQL server. I think I'm missing some pieces of understanding.

I'm following the instructions at https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/relay-modern.html

It details the yarn commands to set up relay and the babel plugin. I added the "relay" script to my package.json like this:

`"relay": "relay-compiler --src ./App --schema ./App/Data/schema.graphql"`

But, when I run `yarn run relay` I get

`Error: --schema path does not exist: /Users/user/dev/react-native-app/App/Data/schema.graphql.`

Yeah. It doesn't exist. Isn't that what this command is supposed to generate? That documentation page doesn't explain what this command outputs, nor what it needs as input. How can I get this command working correctly? Do I really have to hand-write a schema when it already exists on the server?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT, for php**

Given that you are generating your schema on a PHP server, you can generate the `.graphql` file by creating a Node.js script to:

- Send an [introspection query](http://graphql.org/graphql-js/utilities/#introspectionquery) to your `/graphql` endpoint
- Pass the result to [buildClientSchema](http://graphql.org/graphql-js/utilities/#buildclientschema)
- Call [printSchema](http://graphql.org/graphql-js/utilities/#printschema) with it and write it on the disk

---

**General usage with `graphql-js`**

As far as I know, you effectively need your schema printed in GraphQL language. You can have a look at [printSchema](http://graphql.org/graphql-js/utilities/#printschema) for this, to provide it to the relay-compiler.

`printSchema` will do the `JS Object -> Schema Language` conversion. If you already have your schema in Schema Language, this is what you need to provide to the relay-compiler.

It may be possible to use directly the JS Object schema, but I don't know how.

For a detailed explanation of the complete setup, you can look at my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44283394/error-loading-graphql-with-react-relay-modern/44283890#44283890).

Comment: This info definitely helps, but how do I get my schema in GraphQL notation from my server? Is this possible from GraphiQL?

Comment: Calling `printSchema()` on your schema will output it in the GraphQL notation ; you can then save it to a file, named for example `schema.graphql`

Comment: You have to have access to your schema object

Comment: Where am I calling `printSchema()`? In my PHP server?

Comment: Oh, I though you were using `graphql-js`. I'm editing my answer for php.

Comment: Added walkthrough for PHP, let me know if this works for you

Comment: I don't have anything working yet, but over the past few hours I realized that I was working in the Relay Classic example but looking at the Relay Modern documentation. The "tutorial" at https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/tutorial.html prompts you to download the Classic example. The Relay github page has a Modern example in its README.

Comment: Turns out I was barking up the wrong tree. I think I do have to define a schema manually (uggh) in schema.js. I then created a `relay:update-schema` npm script which executes a updateSchema.js script. It's basically identical to https://github.com/relayjs/relay-examples/blob/master/todo-modern/scripts/updateSchema.js which then outputs the schema.graphql. But thanks for your answer, it may be helpful to people in the future.